# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python

Пытаюсь сделать запись в бд таким образом

```
query = 'INSERT INTO users (ip, user, pass) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
val = ("1.1.1.1", "user", "pass")
cursor.executemany(query, val)
```

Но при запуске такая ошибка

я вроде указал, что данные являются строкой, что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: Там разве можно сишные символы-заменители использовать `%s`? По-моему, там используются `?` -> `query = 'INSERT INTO users (ip, user, pass) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'`

Comment: Если вам просто запустить с этими параметрами нужно, то просто execute используйте. executemany нужно, чтобы выполнить запрос много раз с разными параметрами, например создать сразу много пользователей, тогда вторым параметром нужно передать список, в котором каждый из элементов - набор передаваемых в запрос параметров.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как верно заметили в комментариях проблема состоит лишь в том что вы используете executemany - данный метод использует для выполнения сразу нескольких запросов и подразумевает что в `val` у вас будет что-то вроде

```
val = [("1.1.1.1", "user", "pass"),
       ("1.1.1.2", "user2", "pass"),
       ("1.1.1.3", "user3", "pass"),
       ...]
```

таким образом, что бы заработал ваш пример сделайте или

```
query = 'INSERT INTO users (ip, user, pass) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
val = [("1.1.1.1", "user", "pass"),]
cursor.executemany(query, val)
```

или

```
query = 'INSERT INTO users (ip, user, pass) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
val = ("1.1.1.1", "user", "pass")
cursor.execute(query, val)
```

[Здесь](https://proproprogs.ru/modules/metody-execute-executemany-executescript-commit-rollback) очень подробно и красиво рассмотрены все ньюансы использования данных методов